# how to use alsa device hw:0 on xubuntu

Tags: linux, audio, xubuntu, alsa, pulse-audio

I have an audio processing sw designed to use alsa's `hw:0` device. On my xubuntu machine I get the same error as this command line:

```
$ aplay -D hw:0 440.wav 
aplay: main:830: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

this is because pulseaudio own the peripheral:

```
$ fuser -fv /dev/snd/* /dev/dsp*
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  max        7108 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  max        7108 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p:   max        7108 F...m pulseaudio
/dev/snd/timer:      max        7108 f.... pulseaudio
```

here is the list of my card:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I wonder how I can make pulseaudio and this software of mine live together

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio